# How to import a JS Library within my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I'm currently using: https://github.com/naikus/svg-gauge

I would like to customize the library to my specific needs, meaning I can't use the npm package like so as I need to customize the library:

```
import Gauge from 'svg-gauge';
```

I moved the gauge.js file to: `/assets/libs/gauge.js`

And then tried to use it like so:

```
import Gauge from '../../../assets/libs/gauge';
```

This is not working... Is it possible to import this JavaScript library in React allowing me to customize it?

Comment: Your attempt is indeed how you would import the library. Where are you attempting to call the lib from? It also looks like you may have changed the name as it would have otherwise been `import Gauge from '../../../assets/libs/svg-gauge';`

Comment: Thanks but the file is gauge.js in the src: https://github.com/naikus/svg-gauge/tree/master/src

Comment: Does gauge.js export `Gauge`?  What error are you seeing?

Comment: browser is erroring w `Uncaught ReferenceError: k is not defined` within the shallowCopy func in the source: https://github.com/naikus/svg-gauge/blob/master/src/gauge.js

Comment: The variable is not defined. Change k to `var k` on line 96

Comment: wow, that worked. Strange how it didn't cause this error with the npm package but when I use a local js file it does. Thank you so much

Comment: You were likely using the minified version from the npm package that was packaged with a transpiler that corrected this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to be an issue with an undeclared variable `k` in `shallowCopy()` add the declaration to line 96 in `shallowCopy()` like so:

```
function shallowCopy(/* source, ...targets*/) {
   var target = arguments[0], sources = slice.call(arguments, 1);
   sources.forEach(function(s) {
     for(var k in s) {
       if(s.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
         target[k] = s[k];
       }
     }
   });
   return target;
 }
```

You mentioned this was not an issue with the npm package, though it was likely packaged with a transpiler that corrected this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is correct but I feel there might be some mismatch in your path.. If you use Webstorm/IntelliJ you can double check the path by ctrl+click the package and it'll take you to the file.

Comment: Thanks but the path is correct, if it didn't exist, ATOM's ESLINT addon would error